# np.take from 3D matrix given indices of second dimension

Tags: python, numpy

given a 3D array:

```
a = np.arange(3*4*5).reshape(3,4,5)
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]],

       [[40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
        [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
        [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]]])
```

I would like to create the following matrix:

```
result = 
array([[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
       [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]])
```

Using the indices `idx = [1,0,2,2]`
I.e, I would like to "take" per matrix, the row specified in `idx`, where `len(idx)==a.shape[1]` and `np.max(idx)<a.shape[0]` as idx `choose` from dimension 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your array has three dimensions `(x,y,z)`, since you want to take one value for each row in the yth direction, you can do this:

```
a[idx, range(a.shape[1])]
```

Output:

```
array([[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
       [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]])
```